# How to convert a NSString to a String in MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to implement push notifications for MonoTouch but I couldn´t find samples of this anywhere. My problem is trying to read the deviceID into a .NET string.

The output below is just a lot of question marks so I am doing something wrong here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications (UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Converting device ID...");
        NSString s = NSString.FromData(deviceToken, NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
        Console.WriteLine("DEVICE ID IS: " + s);
        s = NSString.FromData(deviceToken, NSStringEncoding.ASCIIStringEncoding);
        Console.WriteLine("DEVICE ID IS: " + s);
         s = NSString.FromData(deviceToken, NSStringEncoding.Unicode);
        Console.WriteLine("DEVICE ID IS: " + s);


    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a great article showing how to do push notifications with MonoTouch:

http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2010/12/implementing-push-notifications-for-ios-with-c-monotouch-using-the-cloud-urban-airship.html

Here's the snippet that does what you want:

```
var str = (NSString)Runtime.GetNSObject (
                Messaging.intptr_objc_msgSend (deviceToken.Handle, new Selector("description").Handle));

var deviceTokenString = str.ToString ().Replace ("<", "").Replace (">", "").Replace (" ", "");
```

Comment: Thanks, he actually made that article based on this question :-)

Answer (score 12):

There is an operator for implicit conversion in MonoTouch.

So you just do:

```
NSString s = NSString.FromData(deviceToken, NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
string csstring = s;
// done
```

Alternatively, you can use `NSString`'s `ToString()` method:

```
NSString s = NSString.FromData(deviceToken, NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
string csstring = s.ToString();
```

[Here's](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/monodoc.ashx?link=T%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.NSString) related documentation.

Comment: Hmmm, still does not give me any device ID though. I just get DEVICE ID=????:?.v?I???????]??????>?l; if I use the ascii encoding. The UTF8 gives me an empty string. So maybe there is something wrong with the push registration? Seems strange though since I get the callback in "RegisteredForRemoteNotifications"

Comment: That's probably another problem. Not a conversion problem. On the NSString you get the value if you print it?

Comment: What do you get as device token? That's your problem I think.

Comment: Here is the code I wanted to write in MonoTouch (look at the first 3-4 lines in "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" method: http://bitbucket.org/urbanairship/push_sample/src/6a5ac0b371ef/APNS/Classes/APNSAppDelegate.m

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out! Thanks for the help! I just had to base64 encode the binary data. I thought they got the device string directly from the binary data, but they base64 encoded it.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to implement this, and I used the following code:

```
NSString newDeviceToken = new NSString(MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr(new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class("NSString").Handle, new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector("stringWithFormat:").Handle, strFormat.Handle, deviceToken.Handle));
string token = newDeviceToken.ToString();
```

This will provide you with a string which reads

```
< 64characterlonghexstring >
```

You can use a Regex to get rid of the spaces and the "<" ">" character as required.

I found the following project very useful in getting a Monotouch implementation of push notifications working:
[C# Apple Push Notification Service](http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/) - it provides client side code as well as server side code.

Comment: Thanks, spot on! I actually just found what I was looking for and Christian Weyer wrote an article based on my request. http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2010/12/implementing-push-notifications-for-ios-with-c-monotouch-using-the-cloud-urban-airship.html